# Connect to database without using session

Tags: java, hibernate, session, jdbc, sessionfactory

Is there a way to connect to database and store my transient object but without using session.

I was asked in an interview if this thing is possible.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to a database you call it **connection**, not *session*. And yes, if you want to write an object to a database you need a **connection** (and also a **transaction**).

**BUT** `transient` means something like *temporary* - you never store transient object into the database. If you mark an attribut as `transient` it won't get loaded/stored during a read or write to the database.